# JQuery Ajax Post method not working with Sharepoint 2010 URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, url, ajax, spurl

I'm trying to send some data to an aspx page by clickin on button but it doesn't seem to work by using jQuery Ajax Post ,however if I just chage the ajax type to GET it works fine ! but I do really want to make it with ajax post method since my transferred data size is really huge!

```
 $('#sendDataBtn').click(function () {
 selecteddata = document.getElementById("<%=textbox.ClientID%>").value; //might be over 1800 caracters
 $.ajax({
      url: '<%=SPContext.Current.Web.Url %>/_admin/CreateFilefromRecievedData.aspx',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: { "data":selecteddata } ,
      headers: {
                "accept": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                "content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }, //==> this fixed everything :)
      error: function () {
          alert("error");
      },
      success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "doesn't seem to work" mean in your case?

Did you verify that the ajax post query is actually being sent (you can see that in your browser developer console).

Comment: no in my browser i got the alert error message

Comment: it doesn't even enter to my CreateFilefromRecievedData.aspx page, I found this but it's with layout folder http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fen-US%2Fsharepointdevelopment%2Fthread%2F2d4ab4ed-29e9-4932-9312-5cc922e397b6&h=tAQGHwDeJ

Comment: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

Comment: change your error() function to the one I provided, it will display more accurate error messages

Comment: it's an internal server error 500 !

Comment: it's not an ajax issue than. check your server-side code and post a new question if needed (hit me on @mehdi__achour when u post the new one, I'll try to have a look)

Comment: just one more question : if the error is in my CreateFilefromRecievedData.aspx page , how come it works fine with the GET method ?

Comment: well, you're maybe doing a specific treatment that fails in your script for the POST method. The GET call doesn't trigger that treatment, so no errors ..

Comment: I fixed it by adding the headers parameter in my ajax indicating that I'm allowing request digesting , still not sure what does tha mean exactely , but I'm on it :)